# Viewpager inside Viewpager make parent Viewpager swipable?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

**Scenario:**

I have a `ViewPager` which contains another `ViewPager`

**Requirement**

I want to disable swipe on child ViewPager, instead parent ViewPager should handle the swipe events.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}
```

I Used the above code to disable swipe events on child ViewPager but parent ViewPager still won't handle the swipe.

Comment: Check `ViewPager` source code, maybe you didn't override some methods because another case parent `ViewPager` detected your swipe.

Comment: I did check `ViewPager` source code but I couldn't come up with anything :(

Comment: I haven't some IDE now to check. Post your code and xml.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the above code in your child ViewPager, use the following:

```
public class NoSwipeViewPager extends android.support.v4.view.ViewPager {

    public NoSwipeViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
        return false;
    }
}
```